# Не получается импортировать модель Django из существующего модуля

Tags: python, django, импорт

Недавно изучаю джанго, пытался создать тег, но в сам файл не получается импортировать модель
[image: так выглядит директория]

```
from django import template
from book_app.models import Book

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def get_books():
    return Book.objects.order_by('title')
```

- это сам файл с тегом

Выходит ошибка: ImportError raised when trying to load 'book_app.templatetags.book_tags': No module named 'bookshop.boo
k_app'

Comment: Пробел в упор не замечаете? 'boo k'

Comment: Вижу, но в самом коде его нет, где же мне тогда его убрать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, проблема была в том, что в одной из папок уже была папка с одноименным названием `book_app`
Тогда правильный импорт будет:

```py
from ..models import Book
```